# How to tell, in VS2010, that a class needs to be disposed?

Tags: visual-studio, idisposable

Is there an easy way, in Visual Studio 2010, to know if a type *needs* to be disposed?

e.g. i write code:

```
Collection<Prize> prizes = new Collection<Prize>();
```

i don't **know** if i need to call dispose.

The way i handle it now is click on `Collection` and press <kbd>F12</kbd>, looking for `IDisposable`:

```
public class Collection<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

then i recursively descend into each class, looking to see if any implement `IDisposable`:

```
public class Collection<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
   public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
      public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
         public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable
            public interface IEnumerable    
         public interface IEnumerable
      public interface IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable    
         public interface IEnumerable
      ...
```

> **Note**: Don't confuse the example with the question. i might have the code:
>
> ```
>  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
> ```
>
> where i then recusively iterate into ancestor types:
>
> ```
>   public sealed class SqlConnection : DbConnection, ICloneable
>       public abstract class DbConnection : Component, IDbConnection, IDisposable
> ```
>
> So i've found that this class needs me to call `Dispose`. But it would be easier if i didn't have to F12 descend into stuff

Comment: VS will complain if you use a using statement with something that doesn't implement IDisposable.  Can you just use that?

Comment: Or use Intellisense.  Start typing "myVariableName.Di"  and see if Dispose comes up in intellisense.

Comment: @Daryl The example code i show happens during an an object's constructor (meaning that my object will now be forced to implement `IDisposable`) (tl;dr: it's not in a `using`)

Comment: @Ian Boyd - I see that would apply to my comment as well.  Good question.

Comment: @IanBoyd basically are you looking for VS to highlight the line an object is instantiated on if it implements IDisposable, so you know you need to use a using statement?

Comment: @Daryl The ideal would be hovering over a class would indicate that it requires disposing. Some places can't use a `using`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the premium or ultimate edition code analysis rule [CA1001:Types that own disposable fields should be disposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182172.aspx) will find types that need to be disposed. To enable code analysis go to the project properties and select the code analysis tab, select Enable Code Analysis on Build, the Microsoft.Design ruleset must be included for the CA1001 rule to run.

Coderush from Devexpress includes similar functionality. This is the only option for the standard edition. There may other add-ins that offer similar functionality.

This cannot be done in the express edition.

Comment: Add "Visual Studio cannot do it", and i'll accept your answer. Addins certainly don't work for Express Editions.